# Windows shows Error Code and won't boot

Tags: windows, lsass

I receive the error message:

> lsass.exe 0xc0000005

What can I do?

I already tried starting in safe mode and rebooting to last the saved configuration and I still get the same error.

Comment: 0xc0000005 indicates an access violation (segfault).

Answer (score 2):

It means a program is reading or overwriting a part of memory it wasn't supposed to.

And it's doing that through the security process, a very critical process. :(

Seems like your computer either has a virus or you have a very unusual program installed... perhaps do a virus check and/or see if you've installed some special kind of software (like antivirus software, a complicated driver, etc.)?